# Notify/check if the content of a custom gutenberg block has changed on save_post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I developed a custom gutenberg block that has some information saved in its attributes. I would like to know if there is a possibility to notify/check only if there is any change in the content of that block when updating the post. Is this possible?